Target url when using Spring Security with Shibboleth/SAML2
I'm trying to implement SSO with Shibboleth/SAML2 in my spring boot application.
All in all, it already works. Now i want to have a certain page (let's say /exams/42) on which a login-button should be, which redirects to Shibboleth and afterward redirects back to the exams page again.
Unfortunately, after the login was successful, i always get redirected to /.
I know this is because / is my default-login-success url.
My login-button is a simple <a href="/saml2/authenticate/shibboleth">login</a>.
I tried to append ?RelayState=/exam/42 or ?target=/exam/42 but without any success.
Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance :)
